# Most effective way of checking a url is alive and redirects anywhere or not?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-redirect

I want to check whether a url is alive and if redirects anywhere i want to get redirected url.

Here is my function but i am not sure whether it is most effective way or not

From effective i mean that minimum amount of data transfer

```
    public static string funcReturnResponseUri(string srUrl)
    {
        Uri siteUri = new Uri(srUrl);
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(siteUri);
        wr.Timeout = 30 * 1000;
        string srReturnUrl = "";
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
            {
                srReturnUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
                response.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return srReturnUrl;
    }
```

C# 4.5 WPF application

Comment: Use the `HEAD` (as opposed to `GET`, `POST` etc) HTTP method

Comment: @Esailija make sure though to fall back to GET if the server returns a 405. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353821/webrequest-head-light-weight-alternative

Comment: @Esailija: In a sane world, I'd agree with you. But my experience with writing a Web crawler is that all too many sites do weird things with HEAD. They often return 405, or they'll return bogus data. In this case I have seen sites not redirect the HEAD request, but redirect the GET request. Weird, I know, but there you have it. In general, I've found HEAD to be unreliable.

Comment: @JimMischel in that case, couldn't you just use GET but close the connection after headers are received?

Comment: @Esailija: Yes. That's effectively what the code above is doing.